# how to display json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i was trying to display values from a local json file but its not working..
here is my code

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xobj.open('GET', 'json/headphones.json'); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

      callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
 };
  xobj.send(null);
 }
  loadJSON(function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
     actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);

     console.log(JSON.stringify(actual_JSON));
       });
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? I have tried with different url ...just working fine. Do you want me to create a snippet:

Comment: its not displaying in console

Comment: Did you try to debug it? What is in your response?

Comment: seems you json is inside the project.. or is it on Server??

Comment: its inside the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `true` in `xobj.open('GET', 'json/headphones.json', true);` line

see this

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xobj.open('GET', 'json/headphones.json', true);
xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
  };
    xobj.send(null);
  }
    loadJSON(function(response) {
   actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
    });
```